# Selecting last date of record where a field has been the same consecutively

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table which contains an `id`, `status_one`, `status_two`, `status_three` and `date'.
This is a kind of log, every couple of minutes a text file is read and the table is populated.

Example Data:

```
Id    |    Status One    |    Status Two    |    Status Three    |    Date
---   |    ----------    |    ----------    |    ------------    |    ----
101   |         5        |        2         |         2          |    2017-04-13 13:48:32 <-
102   |         4        |        2         |         1          |    2017-04-13 13:48:32
103   |         5        |        2         |         2          |    2017-04-13 13:48:32
101   |         5        |        2         |         1          |    2017-04-13 13:38:32 <-
102   |         3        |        2         |         3          |    2017-04-13 13:38:32
103   |         5        |        2         |         1          |    2017-04-13 13:38:32
101   |         3        |        2         |         1          |    2017-04-13 13:28:32 < 
102   |         4        |        2         |         2          |    2017-04-13 13:28:32
103   |         5        |        3         |         1          |    2017-04-13 13:28:32
101   |         5        |        2         |         2          |    2017-04-13 13:18:32 <
102   |         4        |        2         |         2          |    2017-04-13 13:18:32
103   |         5        |        3         |         1          |    2017-04-13 13:18:32
```

In my example `Status One` of record with id `101` has been set as `5` for 10 minutes.
(from `2017-04-13 13:38:32` to `2017-04-13 13:48:32`).

`Status Two` of record with id `101` has been set as `2` for 30 minutes.

The previous value of `Status Three` does not match the current one so it has been `2` for 0 minutes.

How can get the time difference between the last record and the last time that a status stayed as the same value consecutively.

Output Needed For `id` 101

```
Id    |    Status One         |    Status Two         |    Status Three
---   |    ----------         |    ----------         |    ------------ 
101   |  2017-04-13 13:38:32  |  2017-04-13 13:18:32  |  2017-04-13 13:48:32
```

Comment: could you just explain what output you needed in table fromat

Comment: And double-check what you posted.  How has Status Two been 5 for 10 minutes?  It isn't 5 at all...

Comment: Thanks, edited and included output needed.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Worked out another solution,

`SELECT id,date, statusOne
FROM table
WHERE  id = 101 and statusOne <> 5
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.status_one, MAX(a.date) - MIN(a.date) as difference
FROM
(SELECT id, status_one, date
FROM table
WHERE status_one = 5
AND Id IN (SELECT id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE status_one = 5
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 2) a
GROUP BY a.Id, a.status_one;
```

It should give you time difference for `status_one`, you can use similar logic to calculate time difference for `status_two` and `status_three` as well.

Comment: Thanks!  that worked, I only needed the inner SELECT query.

Comment: How is that going to work? Using `COUNT()` without `GROUP BY` will always return one (or zero) rows. So selecting non agregated columns, ordering by non aggregated columns or any `LIMIT` do not make any sense.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel updated the query, thanks for your input.